# Reproducing Camera Reprojection Error

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, camera-calibration, matlab-cvst

I loaded some images into the camera calibration app and exported the resulting camera parameters into a structure called "oldCameraParams". What I want to do now is to reproduce the reprojection error for one of the images used during calibration.
I aim to do this like this:

```
I = imread(imagePath);
[imagePoints,boardSize] = detectCheckerboardPoints(I);
worldPoints = generateCheckerboardPoints(boardSize, squareSize);
squareSize = 30; 
camMatrix = cameraMatrix(oldCameraParams,oldCameraParams.RotationMatrices(:,:,1),oldCameraParams.TranslationVectors(1,:));
projectedPoints = [worldPoints zeros(size(worldPoints,1),1) ones(size(worldPoints,1),1)] * camMatrix;
projectedPoints = bsxfun(@rdivide,    projectedPoints(:,1:2),projectedPoints(:,3));
euclideanDistances = sqrt(sum((imagePoints - projectedPoints) .^2, 2));
meanReprojErrors(ii) = mean(euclideanDistances);
```

I should use the exact same parameters (camera intrinsics, rotation matrix and translation vector) but still my projectedPoints are different than the ones created during calibration and therefore my meanReprojErrors is higher. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting different reprojection errors, because you are not accounting for distortion.  If you call `undistortImage` before calling `detectCheckrboardPoints`, then you should get values that are closer to the reprojection errors computed during calibration.

Comment: Yes, that seemed to be a significant missing step! :) However, if I execute the two last lines of code with the reprojected points from calibration, the error now is high in this case. Which means, that they calculate based on imagePoints not taken from an undistortedImage, right?

Comment: For calibration, the image points are detected in the original "distorted" images. Calibration projects the world points into the image, the same way you do, but then it also distorts the reprojected points, before computing the errors. Sorry, but I am not  quite following what you said about the error being high.  In which case?